# Relaunch Xamarin.Android app after process death

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin.Android MVVMCross app which crash when I come back to it from background but the process was killed by Android OS.

In my BaseActivity I override `OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method where I save process Id before system kills the process

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.PutInt(PROCESS_ID, Process.MyPid());
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In `OnCreate` I check current process id and process saved in bundle:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
    var currentPID = Process.MyPid();

    if (currentPID != savedInstanceState.GetInt(PROCESS_ID))
    {
         var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(SplashScreen));
         intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
         StartActivity(intent);
         Finish();
    }
}
```

This approach is not helpfull. My app crashes anyway.

I just want to restart my app from the SplashScreen.
Please provide me a piece of code to relaunch the app correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,in Android, starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), an Android application no longer have the ability to run freely in the background. For more details about this, you can refer document: [Background Execution Limits in Android 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80).

But you can try to restarted the service once it been finished by a BroadcastReceiver . The function of BroadcastReceiver is to receive a signal when someone or something kills the service; its role is to restart the service.

For more details, you can read an useful article by entering keywords  `Creating a never ending background service in Android` in your browser.
Though it's Java code, it's easy to understand and convert